# How to make the Textview clickable, so that it opens the url in the web browser

Tags: android

sorry for asking this newbie question, as i am new to android development.
what code should be entered in the main.java?

```
<resources>
<string name="strname">Clickable Text<a href="http://domain.com">Visit Website</a></string>
</resources>



<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:autoLink="web"
android:text="@string/strname"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [Linkfy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("http://www.google.com");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

From the documentation

> Linkify take a piece of text and a regular expression and turns all of
>   the regex matches in the text into clickable links

Answer (score 3):

On textview click event write this:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://domain.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

that open the your URL.

Answer (score 3):

Do nothing in Code just include android:autoLink="web" into your Textview XML like

```
<Textview . ..... .....
          android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Above code will work to make any link clickable in TextView String...

Comment: You can also change this link colour using `android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"`

Answer (score 2):

```
 YOURTEXTVIEWNAME.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://domain.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

The terms here you want to know are intent, onClickListener and URI. Welcome newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Html.fromHtml` to convert html tags in your string to links and appropriate formatting and `setMovementMethod` enables automatic handling of link clicks.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String s = getString(R.string.strname);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// request your webservice here. Possible use of AsyncTask and  ProgressDialog
// show the result here - dialog or Toast
}

};);
```

I think this would help you.

And the Most importantly In android view you can define onclick service for any item in view